# Unable to connect to wifi from arch installation iso

Tags: arch-linux, iwd

I tried to install latest arch iso (2024.03.01) but couldn't connect to the WiFi after sort of setting set-property powered on to both adapter (in my case phy0) and device (in my case wlan0). I give the passphrase by both inside `iwd` and from root tty via `iwctl --passphrase ThePassphrase station wlan0 connect TheSSID` but to no avail. I then ran `systemctl --type=service --state=running` and it resulted in these services: dbus-broker.service, getty@tty1.service, iwd.service, ModemManager.service, polkit.service, sshd.service, user @0.service and systemd's : homed, journald,logind, networkd, resolved, timesyncd, udevd, userdbd services. All of these seemed important. So I don't know whether I should stop any of them or not?
Can you help please regarding this issue?